# How to resolve "Possible strict violation" JS-hint error for .apply() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I m getting the error

```
Possible strict violation
```

while running js-hint task of grunt. The error occurred in the following function in my service.

```
var clear = Grid.prototype.clearAllFilters;
service.resetExtend = function (columnBefore, columnDefs) {
        Grid.prototype.clearAllFilters = extendedClearAllFilters;
        function extendedClearAllFilters() {
            clear.apply(this, Grid.prototype.clearAllFilters);
            columnBefore.forEach(function (element, index) {
                if (element.visible) {
                    columnDefs[index].visible = true;
                } else {
                    var x = columnBefore.indexOf(element);
                    columnDefs[x].visible = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

The error is pointing at this point in the function.

```
clear.apply(this, Grid.prototype.clearAllFilters);
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with this line ?

Comment: @JaromandaX js-hints points me to the above line that have error.

Comment: never mind previous comment :D - I get the following: `If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined`

Comment: to be honest - `clear.apply(this, Grid.prototype.clearAllFilters);` doesn't make sense at all as the second argument to function.apply should be an array

Comment: try `Grid.prototype.clearAllFilters = function extendedClearAllFilters() {` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX yo man it worked, where you have been man, thanks ;)